# What is the source of the Infection in "The Walking Dead"?

Tags: tv, the-walking-dead

What was the cause of the virus that turned dead people into zombies? For example, was it after a nuclear blast or explosion? Was the virus in food or water? Or did the virus surface because of a post apocalyptic occurrence?

Comment: "post apocalyptic occurrence" -- can you be more specific as to what this means?

Answer (score 1):

This has not been answered in the show.

In [Series 1 Episode 6](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1628068/?ref_=ttep_ep6), Rick and his group

> reach a Center for Disease Control facility

where they meet Dr Edwin Jenner, a scientist who has been trying to understand the zombie virus. Jenner has more scientific knowledge than any other character in the series so far, and has closely studied the virus; but he doesn't mention anything about its origins, probably because he doesn't know.

However, we can rule out a "nuclear blast or explosion" as the cause of the plague. A large-scale nuclear detonation is [impossible to conceal](http://io9.com/5882973/4-foolproof-methods-for-detecting-secret-nuclear-bomb-tests) and would be international news, but none of the characters has ever mentioned such an event.

Comment: I doubt any of the survivors are equipped to test for radioactive nucleotides in the atmosphere. While I doubt the *Walking Dead* apocalypse has anything to do with nukes, assuming nuclear war was swiftly followed by a plague and societal collapse, it is entirely conceivable for people to be unaware of it. Recall the mystery nuke in *World War Z*, for example.

Comment: @JamesSheridan: Yes, but the mystery nuke in WWZ was detonated *after* the zombie plague had taken hold. If the origin of the plague was related to a nuclear event, that event must have occurred while technological civilization was still functioning, and government agencies, news media, etc. were around to report on it.

Comment: Those sources may not have lasted very long.